# Read/Write to XML file - Visual Basic

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have been using .ReadStartElement/.WriteStartElement to Read from and Write to an XML file.

The issue I have noticed with Reading from the XML file in this way, is that the XML file's elements MUST be in the proper order, if an element is not in it's 'proper' place the .ReadStartElement will fail out (in my experience at least)

Is there a dynamic way to read from an XML file? So I can say in my code "read from this XML file, and give me the information in "FirstName"...and it will go through the file until it finds the FirstName element.

Or maybe a way that I can pull the information in each element and plug it into an array, or something?

Answer (score 0):

Working with an XMLNodeList might get you where you want to go. You can get a collection of all the nodes with a specific name by calling *GetElementsByTagName()* on an XmlDocument object.

This article might help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dc0c9ekk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Luckily VB.NET makes handling XML easy (note that I'm using `XElement` instead of `XmlDocument`):

```
' Read XML file '
Dim xml = XElement.Load(filename)

' Get value of first <FirstName> element '
Dim firstName = xml...<FirstName>(0).Value
```

That's it.

---

If you know the exact level of `<FirstName>`, then you could, given this XML

```
<Foo>
    <Bar>
        <FirstName>A Name</FirstName>
    </Bar>
</Foo>
```

use something like

```
Dim firstName = xml.<Bar>.<FirstName>.Value
```